# Arrays of Generics in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I've been playing around with arrays of generic classes with different types. It's easiest to explain my problem with some sample code:

```
// Obviously a very pointless protocol...
protocol MyProtocol {
    var value: Self { get }
}

extension Int   : MyProtocol {  var value: Int    { return self } }
extension Double: MyProtocol {  var value: Double { return self } }

class Container<T: MyProtocol> {
    var values: [T]

    init(_ values: T...) {
        self.values = values
    }

    func myMethod() -> [T] {
        return values
    }
}
```

Now if I try to create an array of containers like so:

```
var containers: [Container<MyProtocol>] = []
```

I get the error:

> Protocol 'MyProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

To fix this I can use `[AnyObject]`:

```
let containers: [AnyObject] = [Container<Int>(1, 2, 3), Container<Double>(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)]
// Explicitly stating the types just for clarity.
```

But now another 'problem' emerges when enumerating through `containers`:

```
for container in containers {
    if let c = container as? Container<Int> {
        println(c.myMethod())

    } else if let c = container as? Container<Double> {
        println(c.myMethod())
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code above, after determining the type of `container` the same method is called in both cases. My question is:

**Is there a better way to get the `Container` with the correct type than casting to every possible type of `Container`? Or is there something else I've overlooked?**

Comment: wouldn't be the usage of "Linked Lists" be suitable here?
class ContainterNode<T, W> {
    var head: ContainerNode<T>
    var next: ContainerNode<W>?
}

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is a way - sort of - to do what you want - kind of. There is a way, with protocols, to eliminate the type restriction and still get the result that you want, kind of, but it isn't always pretty. Here is what I came up with as a protocol in your situation:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func getValue() -> Self 
}

extension Int: MyProtocol {
    func getValue() -> Int {
        return self
    }
}

extension Double: MyProtocol {
    func getValue() -> Double {
        return self
    }
}
```

Note that the `value` property that you originally put in your protocol declaration has been changed to a method that returns the object.

That's not very interesting.

But now, because you've gotten rid of the `value` property in the protocol, `MyProtocol` can be used as a type, not just as a type constraint. Your `Container` class doesn't even need to be generic anymore. You can declare it like this:

```
class Container {
    var values: [MyProtocol]

    init(_ values: MyProtocol...) {
        self.values = values
    }

    func myMethod() -> [MyProtocol] {
        return values
    }
}
```

And because `Container` is no longer generic, you can create an `Array` of `Container`s and iterate through them, printing the results of the `myMethod()` method:

```
var containers = [Container]()

containers.append(Container(1, 4, 6, 2, 6))
containers.append(Container(1.2, 3.5))

for container in containers {
    println(container.myMethod())
}

//  Output: [1, 4, 6, 2, 6]
//          [1.2, 3.5]
```

The trick is to construct a protocol that *only includes generic functions and places no other requirements on a conforming type.* If you can get away with doing that, then you can use the protocol as a type, and not just as a type constraint.

And as a bonus (if you want to call it that), your array of `MyProtocol` values can even mix different types that conform to `MyProtocol`. So if you give `String` a `MyProtocol` extension like this:

```
extension String: MyProtocol {
    func getValue() -> String {
        return self
    }
}
```

You can actually initialize a `Container` with mixed types:

```
let container = Container(1, 4.2, "no kidding, this works")
```

[Warning - I am testing this in one of the online playgrounds. I haven't been able to test it in Xcode yet...]

Edit:

If you still want `Container` to be generic and only hold one type of object, you can accomplish that by making *it* conform to its own protocol:

```
protocol ContainerProtocol {
    func myMethod() -> [MyProtocol]
}

class Container<T: MyProtocol>: ContainerProtocol {
    var values: [T] = []

    init(_ values: T...) {
        self.values = values
    } 

    func myMethod() -> [MyProtocol] {
        return values.map { $0 as MyProtocol }
    }
}
```

Now you can *still* have an array of `[ContainerProtocol]` objects and iterate through them invoking `myMethod()`:

```
let containers: [ContainerProtocol] = [Container(5, 3, 7), Container(1.2, 4,5)]

for container in containers {
    println(container.myMethod())
}
```

Maybe that still doesn't work for you, but now `Container` is restricted to a single type, and yet you can still iterate through an array of `ContainterProtocol` objects.

Comment: In the OP there was never a need to make the container generic.

Comment: If the OP wanted Container to have an array of MyProtocol objects, Container had to be generic as long as MyProtocol had a required value property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I required `Container` to only store a single type, but that's an interesting solution and I'm sure I'll find some use for it later down the line.

Comment: See my edited answer. I think you can still use a protocol to do what you want to do.

Comment: I ended up taking @Rob Napier's advice and had come up with a different solution. However I feel this provides a nice answer to the original question. Thanks again!

Comment: I would probably take @RobNapier's advice, too :) Solutions like this make it feel like I'm fighting the language. Still, it is nice to know that it is possible in case it is ever necessary.

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. It gets more interesting as you dig into the contents of `values`. It's just `[MyProtocol]`, so the only thing you can call on it is `getValue()`, which will give you dynamic dispatch like polymorphism, but will not let you peek under the covers. The result of `getValue()` is just another `MyProtocol`, not `Int` or `Double`. So you can't apply `+` or any other "number-like" thing that isn't in the protocol, just `getValue()` again. Basically `Self` winds up evaporating and `getValue()` doesn't do anything useful. But still very interesting exploration.

Comment: Yep, in a way, `MyProtocol` just ends up becoming another name for `Any`. To do anything with it you have to cast it to something else eventually...

Comment: I've posted a question concerning rules 2 and 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077159/behaviour-of-protocols-with-self I agree, the behaviour does seem to conflict...

Answer (score 8):

This is a good example of "what did you *want* to happen?" And actually demonstrates the complexity that explodes if Swift had really first-class types.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var value: Self { get }
}
```

Great. `MyProtocol.value` returns whatever type implements it, remembering that this must be determined at compile time, not runtime.

```
var containers: [Container<MyProtocol>] = []
```

So, determined at compile-time, what type is this? Forget the compiler, just do it on paper. Yeah, not sure what type that would be. I mean *concrete* type. No metatypes.

```
let containers: [AnyObject] = [Container<Int>(1, 2, 3), Container<Double>(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)]
```

You know you're going down the wrong road when `AnyObject` has snuck into your signatures. Nothing about this is ever going to work. After `AnyObject` is only sackcloth.

> Or is there something else I've overlooked?

Yes. You need a type, and you haven't provided one. You've provide a rule for constraining a type, but no actual type. Go back to your real problem, and think about it more deeply. (Metatype analysis is almost never your "real" problem unless you're working on a CS PhD, in which case you'd be doing this in Idris, not Swift.) What actual problem are you solving?

Comment: Thank you for your insight. 'What actual problem are you solving?' made me think again about what I was really trying to achieve. Using a different approach to trying to store everything in an array and some refactoring, everything works without using `AnyObject`.

Comment: Swift generics are still raw. And what is simple in other languages, is still not possible or too bulky in Swift. No need to ask OP to go back to the real problem.

Comment: Hey Rob, Your observation helped me a lot as well. I came to a position where i've went "too generic" and instead of using types i just used 'Any' as a workaround. I'm still thinking if i'm going the wrong way or else Swift is still not "mature" enough to do that. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This can be better explained with protocols like `Equatable`. You cannot declare an array `[Equatable]` because while two `Int` instances can be compared to each other and two instances of `Double` can be compared to each other, you cannot compare an `Int` to a `Double` although they both implement `Equatable`.

`MyProtocol` is a protocol, that means it provides a generic interface. Unfortunately, you have also used `Self` in the definition. That means that every type that conforms to `MyProtocol` will implement it differently.

You have written it yourself - `Int` will have `value` as `var value: Int` while a `MyObject` will have `value` as `var value: MyObject`.

That means that a struct/class that conforms to `MyProtocol` cannot be used in place of another struct/class that conforms to `MyProtocol`. That also means that you cannot use `MyProtocol` in this way, without specifying a concrete type.

If you replace that `Self` with a concrete type, e.g. `AnyObject`, it will work. However, currently (Xcode 6.3.1) it triggers a segmentation error when compiling).

Comment: >you cannot compare an Int to a Double -- You can, but Swift lacks automatic casting.

Answer (score 1):

If you try this modified example in a playground, it will systematically crash:

```
// Obviously a very pointless protocol...
protocol MyProtocol {
    var value: Int { get }
}

extension Int   : MyProtocol {  var value: Int    { return self } }
//extension Double: MyProtocol {  var value: Double { return self } }

class Container<T: MyProtocol> {
    var values: [T]

    init(_ values: T...) {
        self.values = values
    }
}


var containers: [Container<MyProtocol>] = []
```

Probably they are still working on this, and things might change in the future.
Anyway as of now, my explanation for this is that a protocol is not a *concrete type*. Thus you do not now how much space in ram something conforming to the protocol will take (for example an `Int` might not occupy the same amount of ram as a `Double`). Thus it might be quite a tricky problem the allocation of the array in ram.
Using an `NSArray` you are allocation an array of pointers (pointers to `NSObjects`) and they all occupy the same amount of ram. You can think of the `NSArray` as an array of the *concrete type* "pointer to `NSObject`". Thus no problem calculating ram allocation.

Consider that `Array` as well as `Dictionary` in Swift are *Generic Struct*, not *objects containing pointers to objects* as in Obj-C.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

I changed the array declaration to be an array of AnyObject so that filter, map and reduce could be used (and also added in a few more objects to check for).

```
let containers: [AnyObject] = [Container<Int>(1, 2, 3), Container<Double>(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), "Hello", "World", 42]
```

This will allow you to check for type in the array and filter before you loop through the array

```
let strings = containers.filter({ return ($0 is String) })

println(strings) // [Hello, World]

for ints in containers.filter({ return ($0 is Int) }) {
    println("Int is \(foo)") // Int is 42
}

let ints = containers.filter({ return ($0 is Container<Int>) })
// as this array is known to only contain Container<Int> instances, downcast and unwrap directly
for i in ints as [Container<Int>] {
    // do stuff
    println(i.values) // [1, 2, 3]
}
```