# Behaviour of Protocols with Self

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I was recently reading [Protocols, Generic Type Constraints and Arrays in Swift](http://letvargo.mooo.com/protocols-generic-type-constraints-and-arrays-in-swift/). My question concerns the following two examples from the blog:

The code:

```
protocol MyProtocol1 {
    var myValue: Self { get }
}

let array: [MyProtocol1] = []  // Error.
```

Produces the error:

> Protocol 'MyProtocol1' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements.

That's expected and there have been several SO questions concerning the topic. However, by changing `myValue` to a function there's no longer any error, yet in both cases `Self` is returned.

```
protocol MyProtocol2 {
    func myValue() -> Self
}

let array: [MyProtocol2] = []  // This is okay.
```

Does anyone know the cause of this seemingly strange behaviour?

Comment: I recommend discussing this on the devforums. I suspect this is a corner case, and may not be intentional. The Swift devs are much more likely to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Did you eventually find an answer to this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

It's explained about 18 minutes into this video:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408

Because your protocol references "self" it can only be used as a generic constraint not as a type.

Example:
Let's say 2 structs implement your protocol - Duke & Silver.

If you made an array of protocol2 ([protocol2]), then your array could contain either Dukes are Silvers.

myValue specifically states that the return value must be self. This means that a Duke must return a Duke and a Silver must return a Silver. As such, you can't have Dukes & Silvers in the same array because their MyValue functions have different return values.

To fix the issue, you can either:

1) Make the return type of myValue protocol2 so that Dukes and Silvers both just return a protocol2 type

2) Make an array of generics that conform to protocol2

Comment: You've missed the point of the question. A protocol with a property of type `Self` -  `var myValue: Self { get set }` - will have `Self or associated type requirements` and will only be able to be used as a type constraint. By contrast, a protocol with a function that returns a value of type `Self` - `func myValue() -> Self` - can be used as a type, and not just a type constraint. The puzzling question is why a protocol *property* requirement of type `Self` has different behavior than a protocol *function* requirement that returns a value of type `Self`.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I did not read the question thoroughly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have definitive answer to this but I feel this may be due to class size and internal layout.

Having a associated type or Self type member will affect the size of object and hence the array size, but using Self as method return type will affect the object size.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but if it were true, you would expect that boxing `Self` would fix it. For instance, if you declared `var myValue: Self? { get }`. This would put the unknown-sized `Self` inside of a known-sized `Optional` and fix the layout problem. (This technique is used for recursive enums, for instance, which have this size problem.) But it doesn't help.