# Can a condition be used to determine the type of a generic?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I will first explain what I'm trying to do and how I got to where I got stuck before getting to the question.

---

As a learning exercise for myself, I took some problems that I had already solved in Objective-C to see how I can solve them differently with Swift. The specific case that I got stuck on is a small piece that captures a value before and after it changes and interpolates between the two to create keyframes for an animation.

For this I had an object `Capture` with properties for the object, the key path and two `id` properties for the values before and after. Later, when interpolating the captured values I made sure that they could be interpolated by wrapping each of them in a `Value` class that used a class cluster to return an appropriate class depending on the type of value it wrapped, or `nil` for types that wasn't supported.

This works, and I am able to make it work in Swift as well following the same pattern, but it doesn't feel Swift like.

---

### What worked

Instead of wrapping the captured values as a way of enabling interpolation, I created a `Mixable` protocol that the types could conform to and used a protocol extension for when the type supported the necessary basic arithmetic:

```
protocol SimpleArithmeticType {
    func +(lhs: Self, right: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, amount: Double) -> Self
}

protocol Mixable {
    func mix(with other: Self, by amount: Double) -> Self
}

extension Mixable where Self: SimpleArithmeticType {
    func mix(with other: Self, by amount: Double) -> Self {
        return self * (1.0 - amount) + other * amount
    }
}
```

This part worked really well and enforced homogeneous mixing (that a type could only be mixed with its own type), which wasn't enforced in the Objective-C implementation.

### Where I got stuck

The next logical step, and this is where I got stuck, seemed to be to make each Capture instance (now a struct) hold two variables of the same mixable type instead of two `AnyObject`. I also changed the initializer argument from being an object and a key path to being a closure that returns an object `()->T`

```
struct Capture<T: Mixable> {
    typealias Evaluation = () -> T
    let eval: Evaluation

    let before: T
    var after: T {
        return eval()
    }

    init(eval: Evaluation) {
        self.eval = eval
        self.before = eval()
    }
}
```

This works when the type can be inferred, for example:

```
let captureInt = Capture {
    return 3.0
}
// > Capture<Double>
```

but not with key value coding, which return AnyObject:\

```
let captureAnyObject = Capture {
    return myObject.valueForKeyPath("opacity")!
}
```

> error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Capture' with an argument list of type '(() -> _)'

`AnyObject` does not conform to the `Mixable` protocol, so I can understand why this doesn't work. But I can check what type the object really is, and since I'm only covering a handful of mixable types, I though I could cover all the cases and return the correct type of Capture. Too see *if* this could even work I made an even simpler example

### A simpler example

```
struct Foo<T> {
    let x: T
    init(eval: ()->T) {
        x = eval()
    }
}
```

which works when type inference is guaranteed:

```
let fooInt = Foo {
    return 3
}
// > Foo<Int>
let fooDouble = Foo {
    return 3.0
}
// > Foo<Double>
```

But not when the closure can return different types

```
let condition = true
let foo = Foo {
    if condition {
        return 3
    } else {
        return 3.0
    }
}
```

> error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Foo' with an argument list of type '(() -> _)'

I'm not even able to define such a closure on its own.

```
let condition = true // as simple as it could be
let evaluation = {
    if condition {
        return 3
    } else {
        return 3.0
    }
}
```

> error: unable to infer closure type in the current context

### My Question

Is this something that can be done at all? Can a condition be used to determine the type of a generic? Or is there another way to hold two variables of the same type, where the type was decided based on a condition?

---

### Edit

What I really want is to:

1. capture the values before and after a change and save the pair (old + new) for later (a heterogeneous collection of homogeneous pairs).
2. go through all the collected values and get rid of the ones that can't be interpolated (unless this step could be integrated with the collection step)
3. interpolate each homogeneous pair individually (mixing old + new).

But it seems like this direction is a dead end when it comes to solving that problem. I'll have to take a couple of steps back and try a different approach (and probably ask a different question if I get stuck again).

Comment: I think the only way to solve this problem is to step back from the current implementation and rethink this closure so that it doesn't return multiple types (that wouldn't look very Swiftly either, after all!)

Comment: After your edit, consider having a look at this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796654/arrays-of-generics-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/davidronnqvist/status/628231101379686400), the type must be known at compile time. Nevertheless, for the simple example at the end of the question you could just explicitly type

`let evaluation: Foo<Double> = { ... }`

and it would work.

So in the case of `Capture` and `valueForKeyPath:` IMHO you should cast (either safely or with a forced cast) the value to the `Mixable` type you expect the value to be and it should work fine. Afterall, I'm not sure `valueForKeyPath:` is supposed to return different types depending on a condition.

What is the exact case where you would like to return 2 totally different types (that can't be implicitly casted as in the simple case of `Int` and `Double` above) in the same evaluation closure?

Comment: I would work for Int and Double, but in my full example I also have cases for CGPoint, CGSize, CGRect, CATransform3D, etc.

Comment: I was afraid so. Still, it's not clear to me why do you want to have a single closure returning multiple different types. Where are you going to store this `Capture` values anyway?

Comment: If I got you right, you wanted the captures to be homogeneous indeed. So at any given time you won't have a list of Capture<CGPoint> mixed together with Capture<CGRect>, right? That's the reason there is still a way to solve the problem. I would just like to see some snippets where you actually use these captures

Comment: Ah. I can't have that mixes Capture<Int> and Capture<Double> ... can't believe I never checked that :(. Then it seems generics isn't the solution to my problem here.

Comment: But let's suppose that you can instead, and that you can have a list of `Capture<Whatever>`. How would you process the list? You can't just mix every value with the others since anyway `Capture` has the `Self` requirement. I'm still missing something :-/

Comment: I only want to mix each pair (before + after). So my ideal case would be a heterogeneous collection of homogeneous pairs.

Answer (score 0):

> in my full example I also have cases for CGPoint, CGSize, CGRect, CATransform3D

The limitations are just as you have stated, because of Swift's strict typing. All types must be definitely known at compile time, and each thing can be of only one type - even a generic (it is resolved by the way it is called *at compile time*). Thus, the only thing you can do is turn your type into into an umbrella type that is much more like Objective-C itself:

```
let condition = true
let evaluation = {
    () -> NSObject in // *
    if condition {
        return 3
    } else {
        return NSValue(CGPoint:CGPointMake(0,1))
    }
}
```

Comment: but then `NSObject` can't conform to `Mixable` anymore

Comment: @Vik I'm totally with you there.