# Declare a function in Swift that returns a closure with a generic T.Type

Tags: swift, generics

we are trying to make a function in Swift , that returns a closure. The return type is as follows:

```
func completionBlock() -> (Response<T, NSError>) -> ()
```

where Response itself is a struct with 2 generics. The second will be always NSError, but the first depends on a switch.

Declaration of Response:

```
public struct Response<Value, Error: ErrorType> { ...
```

What we want to achieve is a function that will return a closure with a type that depends on a value of variable. 
Depending on this value, and with a switch, it specifies one type or another, the only requirement for the generic parameter is that it must conform to a specific protocol, but we can't find a solution.

What we got so far is:

```
class BaseClass {
    var endpoint: Int
    ... 

    func completionBlock() -> (Response<T, NSError>) -> () {

        switch endpoint
        {
        case 1:
            return getHandleResponseClosure(Car.self)
        case 2:
            return getHandleResponseClosure(Truck.self)
        }
    }

    func getHandleResponseClosure<T: Mappable>(_: T.Type) -> (Response<T, NSError>) -> () {

        let closure = { (_: Response<T, NSError>) -> () in
            // ...
        }
        return closure
    }

}
```

But this don't compile: *"Use of undeclared Type T"* at **func completionBlock()**, the type at this point is generic, it only requires to conform to protocol Mappable, but we don't know how to specify this.

Thanks!!, Greetings

Comment: drop the whole generics, create a common superclass/-protocol of Car and Truck and your are good to go - I see no use for generics here. It will only create problem after problem. In terms of the error message you have to specify `func completionBlock<T>() ...` but that will yield expected and correct errors and so on until you will end up calling `getHandleResponseClosure(T)` at which point you will have removed and use of your code.

Comment: The basic problem is that Car and Truck have nothing to do with T and therefore you cannot convert them.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814457/can-a-condition-be-used-to-determine-the-type-of-a-generic?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are other problems with your code, the fundamental one is that generic types in method signatures must be declared directly after the name of the method. Take a look at `completionBlock` below. This code compiles and works.

```
struct Response<T, E: Error> {

}

struct Car {}
struct Truck {}

class BaseClass {

    func completionBlock<T>() -> ((Response<T, NSError>) -> ()) {
        return { response in /* What goes here? */ }
    }

}

let c = BaseClass()
let r: (Response<Car, NSError>) -> () = c.completionBlock()
```

On a side note, I would replace `struct Response<T, E: Error>` with…

```
enum Response<T> {
case success(T)
case error(Error)
}
```